# Ubuntu 20.04 Wayland fractional scaling and multiple monitors hidden UI elements

Tags: multiple-monitors, wayland, hdpi

I'm using multiple monitors with different DPI and fractional scaling.
When I open some window, such as Nautilus, some UI elements are hidden and when I hover over the elements its shows.
The below video can show to you the behaviour.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h094iztZ26k

Answer (score 0):

Fractional scaling and multiple monitors is one of the biggest issues with Ubuntu at the moment. Adding onto the problem it seems like you want to use more than one extra monitor.

You best bet right now is to play with the setting in `xrandr` and set specific resolutions and scaling for each monitor.

Does your laptop have HiDPi? In this case it is one of the most known and unsolved problems with Ubuntu, but you best bet is trial and error with xrandr.